# Может ли корпоративный HTTP-прокси мешать запуску юзербота на Pyrogram?

Tags: python, pyrogram

Правильно ли я понимаю, что Pyrogram полностью эмулирует реального пользователя, или же там авторизация проходит по несколько другой схеме? Просто дело в том, что авторизация в Telegram через браузер (с использованием того же HTTP-прокси) проходит без проблем, а попытка запустить юзербота выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "collector2.py", line 316, in <module>
  File "asyncio\runners.py", line 44, in run
  File "asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
  File "collector2.py", line 314, in main
  File "collector2.py", line 309, in fun1_async
  File "collector2.py", line 75, in collecting
  File "pyrogram\client.py", line 311, in aenter
  File "pyrogram\methods\utilities\start.py", line 58, in start
  File "pyrogram\methods\auth\connect.py", line 40, in connect
  File "pyrogram\client.py", line 637, in load_session
  File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 274, in create
  File "pyrogram\session\auth.py", line 84, in create
  File "pyrogram\connection\connection.py", line 48, in connect
  File "pyrogram\connection\transport\tcp\tcp_abridged.py", line 32, in connect
  File "pyrogram\connection\transport\tcp\tcp.py", line 79, in connect
  File "concurrent\futures\thread.py", line 58, in run
  File "socks.py", line 47, in wrapper
  File "socks.py", line 787, in connect
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
[8448] Failed to execute script 'collector2' due to unhandled exception!
```

Код программы - стандартный, из примера в документации Pyrogram: https://docs.pyrogram.org/intro/quickstart